# Searching inside HtmlNode using Xpath '//'

Tags: asp.net, html-agility-pack

I am parsing Web page using HTML agility pack where i traverse down to each required childnode
Here's how i am doing

```
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://example.com");
HtmlNode list = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//ol[@class='list']")
foreach (HtmlNode inside_li in linode.ChildNodes)
{
  if (inside_li.Name == "div")
    {
       HtmlNode ahref = inside_li.SelectSingleNode("//h3[@desc='title']/a");
    }
}
```

Website Structure:-
There are many ol with attrib class='list' each have a div which have h3 with atrrib desc='title' somewhere inside (location of h3 cannot be fixed).

Question:-
Suppose if store ahref attrib ["href"] in array of 10 . then all elements have same String of first one. So i figured out using // it is referening the whole document http://example.com. for this case how can we search anywhere in inside_li HtmlNode.
And why this problem is occurring even when I am telling to search inside of inside_li not whole document

Answer (score 2):

If you want to look only from the current node, just remove the // in an XPATH expression, for example:

```
inside_li.SelectSingleNode("h3[@desc='title']/a");
```

/ means "from the root"

// means "from the root" and "recursively"

Comment: I tried your option but is doesn't worked. Then i used '.' which means current node and i searched relative to that now my xpath is .//h3[@desc='title']/a and it worked. Can you explain why this is happanign because InnerHTML of inside_li only have only have one h3 tag at the given time. how it is detecting others which are not in current foreach loop.

Comment: `.` means the current node, `.//` means search nodes recursively from the current node, so it probably means `h3` is not a direct child from inside_li but a grand child

Comment: so does that mean using forloop for each HtmlNode in somenode.ChildNode is of no use ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. It depends on what you want to achieve

Comment: Suppose there is one master div in which there are many div's and each div have one h3[@desc='title'](the one which is required). So I assigned master div to HtmlNode HN and searched every childnode in HN(using foreach loop). And inside loop I searched for **h3** value but using your xpath h3[@desc='title']/a returns me the first h3 tag in whole html document irrelevant of current loop scope.